# How to get the API Endpoint of a SoapUI TestStep using Java

Tags: java, api, testing, soapui

I would like to know how to get the API end point of a TestStep in SoapUI Xml using Java.
[image: SoapUI image]

I have used the following,

```
        for (int i=0; i<numberOfTestSteps; i++) {
                WsdlTestStep testStep = testCase.getTestStepAt(i);

                WsdlTestCaseRunner runner = new WsdlTestCaseRunner(testCase, new StringToObjectMap());
                runner.runTestStep(testStep);

                List<TestStepResult> resultList = runner.getResults();
                for (TestStepResult result : resultList) {
        String endPoint = ((MessageExchange)result).getEndpoint();
        System.out.println("End Point = " + endPoint);
    }
}
```

It only gives "www.test.com:8080". But I need the API end point as in the image.

Please someone help me to solve this.

Comment: Are you using `Script Assertion`? Could not get where you are using java.

Comment: No I am using Java to execute SoapUI XML file. In that case, I need to print the API end point of a TestCase.

Comment: What do you mean by `soapui xml`?

Comment: The xml file generated after saving the soapui project

Comment: Can you share the test case structure / sequence of steps? Also some more context of java code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Below should give you what you are looking for:

```
String resourcePath = ((MessageExchange)result).getResource().getFullPath();
System.out.println("Resource Path = " + resourcePath);
```

You may look at respective [SoapUI's API](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/teststeps/RestResponseMessageExchange.html)

There is very simply way too if you wish to show that value from with SoapUI Project itself.

In the test case, there might be a `REST Request` Test step type. Add a [Script Assertion](https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/validating-messages/getting-started-with-assertions.html) as shown below:

```
log.info messageExchange.endpoint
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your code. But it shows "getResource()" as a cannot resolve method. Here is a sample snippet of my code.

WsdlTestCaseRunner runner = new WsdlTestCaseRunner(testCase, new StringToObjectMap());
            runner.runTestStep(testStep);

            List<TestStepResult> resultList = runner.getResults();
            for (TestStepResult result : resultList) {

Comment: Can you edit the question and updated it with your code? By the way, it does have the code that you actually in the question?

Comment: Updated. Please check it

Comment: Can you please clarify, what are the test steps in the test case? or screen shot of the test case would also help. More over if `endpoint` (which you mentioned in the question) worked, then above should also work.